# Adding options to a dynamically loaded select

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-select

Which is the best way to add `<option>...</option>` to a select that has been dynamically added to the dom?

I mean at a generic `<select>` that has been added subsequently an ajax call. I would like to add the option before showing the select element.

thanks!

**EDIT**

This is the function that I have

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: baseUrl + 'MyService.asmx/NewReferent',
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        // Get the referent item from the webservice
        var referent = msg.d;
        // Render the template with the Referent data
        var referentTemplate = $("#referentTemplate").tmpl(referent);
        //add button style
        $(".button", referentTemplate).button();
        //Show the Dialog
        $("#referent-dialog").empty().html(referentTemplate).dialog('open');
    }
});
```

This is the code that I have to get the options from the server

```
$.getJson(baseUrl + 'MyService.asmx/GetReferentTypes', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        $('#select_id').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value));
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2**

Unfortunately I am not able to understand what's going on with my code. With some little modification to the code of @Raynos I have been able to receive the following JSON data from the server

```
{"d":
    [
        {"__type":"Full.Namespace.Path.ReferentType","ReferentTypeID":1,"Description":"option1"},
        {"__type":"Full.Namespace.Path.ReferentType","ReferentTypeID":2,"Description":"option2"}
    ]
}
```

that is not parsed correctly from my `$.each()` function call. I have two question now:

- Who's going to add the _type parameter?
- How can I correct the parsing `each()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("<select>").append(
    $("<option>" , {
        text: "foo",
        value: "bar"
    })
).appendTo("#container");
```

The trick is to append the options before you append the select to something.

Alternatively you can make sure to hide the select before you add it to the DOM.

pseudo code:

```
$.when(ajax).then(function(html) {
    var foo = $(html);
    foo.find("select.SomeClass").hide();
    ...
});

...

$("select.SomeClass").append($("<option>")).show()
```

**[[Edit]]**

Use a simple bit of `$.when` magic to make sure they happen in the write order. I.e. the select template is created then the options are appended

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: baseUrl + 'MyService.asmx/NewReferent',
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Get the referent item from the webservice
            var referent = msg.d;
            // Render the template with the Referent data
            var referentTemplate = $("#referentTemplate").tmpl(referent);
            //add button style
            $(".button", referentTemplate).button();
            //Show the Dialog
            $("#referent-dialog").empty().html(referentTemplate).dialog('open');
        }
    }); 
}).then(function() {
    $.getJson(baseUrl + 'MyService.asmx/GetReferentTypes', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $('#select_id').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value));
        });
    });
});
```

**[[Edit 2]]**

Give your sample JSON structure

```
$.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
    $('#select_id').append(
        $("<option></option>")
          .attr("value", value.ReferentTypeID)
          .text(value.Description)
    );
});
```

Would generate

```
<option value="0">option1</option>
<option value="1">option2</option>
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a bunch of markup that is returned from an ajax call and here there is my select. I have to show the markup inside a dialog and before of that I have to add the options. How can I do in this case?

Comment: @Lorenzo you want to not show the empty select box before you add the options?

Comment: @Raynos it's ok to show it. I am just getting confused on where to insert my code. Please have a look at my question edit for details.

Comment: @Lorenzo would `$.when().then()` do to make sure they run in proper order?

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I am looking for... but unfortunately it is not working on mi site. The code is correctly executed in the correct order but no options get added... I am going to debug a little bit my code...

Comment: @Lorenzo try `console.log(data)` and also make sure to call `.getJSON()` note the capital letters.

Comment: Sorry but I have got completely lost on this.... Can you have a look to my second edit please?

Comment: @Lorenzo I think `__type` is C# storing the C# Class of your object. I think you want the value to be ReferentType and text to be Description. See edit 2.

Comment: @Raynos: there are no errors with your latest suggestion. I have stepped on the code through Firebug. But the options does not get added to the select anyway....

Comment: @Lorenzo did you replace `'#select_id'` with your real id?

Comment: @Raynos: Yes. The only remaining problem, that I have just solved now, was a typo on the id of the select. Everything works smoothly now. Thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

This simple answer may be help you,

```
var selectField = $('#' + id_of_field);
var empIds = [101, 102, 103];
var empNames = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'];
var options = '';
selectField.empty();
for ( var i = 0, len = empIds.length; i < len; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + empIds[i] + '">' + empNames[i] + '</option>';
}
selectField.append(options);
```